# Pattern match is redundant

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Haskell, Stack build tool.

I have code:

```
quote :: Char
quote = '\''

doubleQuote :: Char
doubleQuote = '\"'

isBorder :: Char -> Bool
isBorder quote = True
isBorder doubleQuote = True
isBorder _ = False
```

It will be compiled without erors, but I see the messages during the compilation:

> D:\haskell\real\app\Main.hs:34:1: warning: [-Woverlapping-patterns]
>       Pattern match is redundant
>       In an equation for `isBorder': isBorder doubleQuote = ...
>
> D:\haskell\real\app\Main.hs:35:1: warning: [-Woverlapping-patterns]
>       Pattern match is redundant
>       In an equation for `isBorder': isBorder _ = ...

What does it mean? I don't see redundance...

Comment: You should also see a "shadowing" warning, if you enable warnings with `-Wall`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When declaring functions, the argument variables are *new* names. Your quote and doubleQuote are shadowing the functions rather than invoking the functions for pattern matching. In this way the language of pattern matching subtly deviates from the language of right-hand-sided expressions. To achieve what you want, either do

```
isBorder :: Char -> Bool
isBorder '\'' = True
isBorder '\"' = True
isBorder _ = False
```

or

```
isBorder :: Char -> Bool
isBorder c | quote == c = True
isBorder c | doubleQuote == c = True
isBorder _ = False
```

The philosophy is to first bind the argument to name and *then* to use a guard to invoke an expression that evaluates to a boolean.

Comment: You can pack all the calls in one top-level function.

Comment: Yes, I understand you and I think you are right. Hm... But I see that my code works right too... So Haskell understands what I meaned in my definitions. Look my full code example, please here: https://yadi.sk/d/MfyG7OmHwGmsV

Answer (score 4):

The pattern can only be matched against concrete values, not against identifiers.

So the compiler essentially sees:

```
isBorder x = True
isBorder x = True
```

since `quote` and `doublequote` aren't the defined identifers but the names of the parameters.

Comment: > *since quote and doublequote aren't the defined identifers but the names of the parameters.*  
Hm... But I see that my code works right... So Haskell understands what I meaned in my definitions.

Comment: Really? Is `isBorder '5'` false?